# How to Return data from database to dropdown menu using Spring

Tags: java, database, spring, drop-down-menu, app-startup

How to retrieve the data from database to dropdown menu on page load using spring...Is it possible?
When i click the dropdown box it has to show the namelist that is available in database.

Comment: Are you using Spring MVC here ?

Comment: ya...i'm using spring mvc only..please help me